# Pass info between collection views that have been embedded in different view controllers

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, segue, embed

So I have 2 view controllers, the one shown on the left has 1 embedded collectionview in it and the one shown on the right has 2 embedded collectionviews in it.

[image]

when trying to pass data (packSelected) from one to another, the prepareforsegue method doesn't work as i want it to change view controllers and the information is coming from the UICollectionViewController class.  so at the moment I'm using the following code to 'segue' between the 2 view controllers from the UICollectionViewController class when a cell of the collectionview which is embedded in the the left hand viewcontroller is selected:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: PackCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PackCollectionViewCell

    //cell.labelCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    //cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])

    cell.labelCell.text = packsDescription[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: packsImage[indexPath.row])

    cell.imageCell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.imageCell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageCell.frame.height/2

    cell.imageCell.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cell.imageCell.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromHEX(hexValue: 0x62aca2).cgColor        
    return cell        
}

var packSelected: String = ""

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    print(packsName[indexPath.row])        
    packSelected = packsName[indexPath.row]        
    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "packView2Journey", sender: self)
    transportMe() 
}

func transportMe()  {        
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: JourneyViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "JourneyViewController") as! JourneyViewController
    let currentController = getCurrentViewController()
    currentController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController? {

    if let rootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        var currentController: UIViewController! = rootController
        while( currentController.presentedViewController != nil ) {
            currentController = currentController.presentedViewController
        }
        return currentController
    }
    return nil
}
```

The problem with this is now that I can't send any data to the other collectionview (s) that are embedded in the right hand viewcontroller.

--------------- EDIT ---------------------------------

solved with delegate method.

in the collectionviewcontroller that will pass the information declare the delegate:

```
class PackCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    weak var delegate: PackCollectionViewDelegate?
//....
}
```

then below create delegate class:

```
protocol PackCollectionViewDelegate : class {
    func packSelected (_ selector: PackCollectionViewController, didSelect thePackName: String)
}
```

and in the function that calls transportMe() as shown in original post define the data to be passed:

```
let passPackName = packsName[indexPath.row] as String
self.delegate?.packSelected(self, didSelect: passPackName)
transportMe()
```

in the collectionviewcontroller that will receive the information create extension:

```
extension PartCollectionViewController : PackCollectionViewDelegate {
    func packSelected (_ selector: PackCollectionViewController, didSelect thePackName: String) {
        print(thePackName)
    }
}
```